# error for varying types for CASE when updating cells

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So I'm trying to update some cells based on a condition if brand_name is robinhood then we put product as crypto, i tried the code below in redshift but I get the error

```
ERROR:  CASE types character varying and boolean cannot be matched
```

```
select *,
case brand
when 'robinhood'
then business_unit_product::varchar = 'crypto'
else business_unit_product::varchar
end 
from tickets;
```

what should I change?

Comment: Don't use SELECT, use UPDATE to update table data.

Comment: @jarlh How would i do that? what would the code look like?

Answer (score 1):

The following updates the `business_unit_product` to `'crypto'` for all rows where the `brand` currently equals `'robinhood'` *(and makes no changes to the other rows)*...

```
UPDATE
  tickets
SET
  business_unit_product = 'crypto'
WHERE
  brand = 'robinhood'
```